# Sql query like pivot table from vertical list in postgresql effectively

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I want to write an sql query like pivot table from vertical list. Let's see it on an example:

My table data:

Table1 -> Metadata:

```
id text  
1  t1
2  t2
3  t3
```

Table2 -> Report:

```
date          category      revenue  metadata_id
2020-01-01    TRIAL           1          1
2020-01-01    PURCHASE       1.2         2
2020-01-03    SUBSCRIPTION   1.4         3
2020-01-03    PURCHASE       1.1         3
```

...

In here, I want to create an sql query to get resul from specific range and ids filter like:

```
Request:
start-date: 2020-01-01
end-date: 2020-01-30
ids: 1,2....100
```

Expected result:

```
id       text       category_trial      category_purchase   category_SUBSCRIPTION
1         t1             1                      0                     0
2         t2             0                      1.2                   0
3         t3             0                      1.1                  1.4
```

In here, I wrote an sql like below:

```
select
m.id,
m.text,
t1.rev as category_trial,
t2.rev as category_purchase,
t3.rev as category_SUBSCRIPTION
from metadata m
left join 
(
  select 
metadata_id,
sum(revenue) as rev
from report where category = 'TRIAL' and report_date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
group by  metadata_id
) t1 on t1.metadata_id = m.id 
left join 
(
  select 
metadata_id,
sum(revenue) as rev
from report where category = 'PURCHASE' and report_date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
group by  metadata_id
) t2 on t2.metadata_id = m.id 
left join 
(
  select 
metadata_id,
sum(revenue) as rev
from report where category = 'SUBSCRIPTION' and report_date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30'
group by  metadata_id
) t3 on t3.metadata_id = m.id 
...
```

In here I have more than 7 categories.

My problem in here, this sql is working but the performance is not enough. Is there any suggestion to improve performance of it?

Note: I wrote it in postgresql and I use indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use Postgres often, but this query should be faster:

```
select id, text,
       sum(case category when 'TRIAL'        then revenue else 0 end) cat_tri,
       sum(case category when 'PURCHASE'     then revenue else 0 end) cat_pur,
       sum(case category when 'SUBSCRIPTION' then revenue else 0 end) cat_sub   
  from (
    select id, text, category, revenue 
      from metadata m join report r on m.id = r.metadata_id
      where date_ between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-30' 
        and id between 1 and 100 ) t   
  group by id, text 
  order by id
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fe9c38499661283dadea524b81034dce)

Result as expected, only one join, filtering and grouping.

Comment: Actually, you do not even need a [subquery](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=05781f14fd142dc7a625e4c4c00de834). Also, be sure to qualify *every* field in `JOIN` queries with table or alias whether it is Postgres or not.